# NodeRed flow iteration (split) issue

Tags: split, node-red

I have a flow in which I query a DB, the response populate and array of msg.payload. I then use a Split to iterate over the msg.payload so I have multiple flow iterations, one for each msg.payload.
After the split I make a call to Watson NLU, this node is always called and then I have a script node where I do some variable mapping. This last node is not called at every iteration of msg.payload. Sometimes is nor executed at all, sometimes 1, never for each array item.

Any clue why this can happen?

Comment: There isn't enough information here to be able to help. Are there any errors/warnings logged in the debug sidebar or the logs?

Comment: I think I found the reason of the problem, in the step after NLU my function makes tests to verify if the element I am expecting (to save in the db) exists or not:
msg.db.SENTIMENT = (msg.features.sentiment.document.label || "NA");
I believe this is a bad way to make the test and assign a default value, working on how to make this better